# Prevent credential roaming for certain accounts/certificates?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I want to use credential roaming in Windows 7, 8 and 10 for EFS certificates, so users can access their encrypted files from any computer they login to.

However, some of these users will also have more important certificates, ones used for things like private key recovery or certificate enrollment.  I don't want those credentials automatically available on any computer they login to.

Is there any way to prevent certain certificates from roaming?  Or if not, disable it for certain users?

Answer (score 1):

I have never actually done this. But here's a few things Google brought up:

> Is there any way to prevent certain certificates from roaming?

[MS says to link them to a different account altogether, or put them on a smart card](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779389).

> Or if not, disable it for certain users?

Because [CR works with a user GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759556), you could [deny some users "apply group policy" permissions to that GPO](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/05/how-to-exclude-individual-users-or-computers-from-a-group-policy-object/).